# how to trigger Express get route using websocket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I would update my client side view every insert in the database.

In y angular application I have a function that adds text to database :

```
ajoutText(newtext: String) {

  this.dataService.sendtext(newtext)
  .subscribe(res => this.socket.emit('save-message', { data: "hello" }));   
  }
```

after posting message to database I emit a socket. the idea is to trigger  a get route to update my observable in Angular side with the new data, and create a data stream.

Here's my server configuration :

**server.js**:

```
var http = require("http");
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var firebase = require("firebase");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var port = process.env.app_port || 8080; // set our port
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var server = app.listen(port);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
var routerProj = require("./routes/routes");

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT ,DELETE');

  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,*");
  next();
});
var config = {
  ... configuration...
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);


var serviceAccount = require("./ServiceAcountKey.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://datatable-18f93.firebaseio.com"
});
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  req.io = io; // pass socket to route 
  next();
});
app.use("/v1", routerProj);
```

and **routes.js** file :

```
var express = require("express"); // call express
var router = express.Router(); // get an instance of the express Router
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
//module.exports = function (req) {
//router.route("/")

router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  // Test
  console.log(req.io.sockets)

  next();
});
router
  .route("/")
  .get(function (req, res, err) {
    // Get a database reference to our posts
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref("/");

    // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
    ref.once("value", function (snapshot) {
      var list = [];
      snapshot.forEach(function (elem) {
        list.push(elem.val());
      })
      list = JSON.stringify(list);    
      res.send(list);


    }, function (errorObject) {
      console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
      res.status(500).send(errorObject.code);
    });
  });

router
  .route("/")
  .post(function (req, res, err) {
    console.log(req.body);
    // Get a database reference to our posts
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref("/");

    // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
    ref.push(
      {
        "text": req.body.text
      }

    );

  });

//return router;

//}
module.exports = router;
```

How can I run post route on `save-message` emit from client side ?